# TypeScript error when defining property of named function expression with 'let' but not const

Tags: typescript

So, I'm reading through the TypeScript [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) and ran across a particular oddity when reading about Call Signatures. Please see this code provided by the handbook:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
 description: string;
 (someArg: number): boolean;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
 console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

I wanted to try creating a function that doSomething would run. But ran into a problem with defining the function as a named expression using `let`. Specifically, I get the error `"Property 'description' does not exist on type '(n: number) => boolean'.(2339)"` **when assigning the description property**. but defining the function as a function declaration, or with `const` allows me to assign the property just fine... Why is that?

Please see below for an example.

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

function f(n:number){
  return true;
}

f.description = "bla bla bla";

let testFunc = function f(n: number) {
    return true;
}

testFunc.description = "bla bla bla"; //This shows an error!!

const testFunc2 = function f(n: number) {
    return true;
}
testFunc2.description = "bla bla bla";
```

Comment: Because if you use let you could change the function at runtime to one that may not be a DescribableFunction, whereas with const the compiler is apparently smart enough to infer that you want a DescribableFunction (and it knows it can't change). I'm surprised/impressed that the second one works, I'm not the least surprised the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript 3.1 introduced support for [declaring properties on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368).
Specifically, you can

> define properties on function declarations and `const`-declared functions

as you have seen in your `f` and `testFunc2` examples.  Before TypeScript 3.1, all three of those examples would have failed.  `let`-declared functions are not included in that functionality.  That's the only *authoritative* answer I can give you, because I don't see a rationale for excluding in GitHub or the release notes.

---

Note that in order to support `let` or `var` declared functions, the compiler would need to account for the possibility of the function being *reassigned*, which would be more complicated to track.  That is, nothing stops you from writing

```
testFunc = () => false; // okay
```

somewhere in your code base, and then the compiler would need to figure out *if* and *when* `testFunc` has a `description` property via control flow analysis.  On the other hand, neither functions declared via `function` statements nor `const` variables can be reassigned, so there's no control flow issue to worry about.

So, even though I don't have an authoritative answer, I would speculate that property declarations on reassignable functions were never supported because it would have been more difficult to do so property, and nobody has been clamoring for such a feature.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwFgAoKKAEwRVTHKoC4o8YGmIBzANws2ACngUAthACCyMYOKEF6CMgCUg9BQp5MxKcwC+FlgDMSZStXYUAyoojAAFqnEzbxIJwSGhYuAQOfMR6DNJQiFTyeAB0OBRi-sTJnCE8UVAA1FAARFDInoTIxBDsJYVQATIAbHp6FpYsdpFODTKBUJraujFMrGUVVVAihBDtncy22VxovD10xbiYUJvbOJjFNsx4wFMIwESktA3dVL39gzr6sWPlwJXU07MsHczzwGcXRBLXKrW7rHYQvYHKAAehhABUfPAhF4KAB3ZFmKC6ZAUZAAQnxfwBDiuMhiNAAfA1MDh4LNYTCoBQANaYEDzBLEYSnYSAgBMV3spHytj6Gi0jxGcVe7ymyBmc2Y-z5Dn5wO4oOo4L2uy2mwOQA)